# How to play a sound based on a random number

Tags: javascript, html

I try to play a sound file based on a result from a Math.random between 1-4. I building a "Simon Game" using JavaScript and want to play a specific sound file ( 1 of 4 based on the current flashing box). I have stored the 4 sounds file inside an object like  this:

```
let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
let sounds = {
      box1: new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"),
      box2: new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3"),
      box3: new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"),
      box4: new Audio ("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3")
};
```

How can I operate the sound based on random result?

Regards

Comment: `sounds["box" + random]` Why aren't you using an array for `sounds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(sounds).length - 1);    
sounds[`box${random}`].play();
```

An array might better suite your use-case though, as it prevents the use of `Object.keys()`.

Comment: Should use `.length - 1`, in case `Math.random()` return 1 you end up accessing value out of limit,

Comment: LucHermkens & Code Maniac --  Many thanks! Solved it by turn it into an array and use the .length - 1.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the code just add:

```
sounds['box'+random].play();
```